# How to prove that averaging averages of different partitions of a dataset produces the same overall average

Tags: mean, proof

After testing some cases, it appears to be true that if you create partitions in a dataset, average the data in the partitions, then average the averages, you get the same result as if you averaged the entire dataset.

For instance:

avg(1,3,5,8,4,2) = 3.8333
avg(1,3,5) = 3
avg(8,4,2) = 4.6667
avg(3, 4.6667) = 3.8333

I'd like to be able to show that this is always true. Any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Comment: This would be true only if the partitions have an equal size.

Comment: or, equivalently, if each partition is weighted by its size

Comment: The process becomes more transparent if you re-cast the situation in terms of *sums* rather than averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's partition our $N$ elements into two sets with sizes $N_1,N_2$ and sums $S_1,S_2$.

The averages will be: $\frac{S_1}{N_1},\frac{S_2}{N_2}$

The average of this will be: $0.5(\frac{S_1}{N_1}+\frac{S_2}{N_2})$

**If we assume the sizes are equal** then $N_1=N_2=0.5N$ and we get:

$0.5(\frac{S_1}{N_1}+\frac{S_2}{N_2})=0.5(\frac{S_1+S_2}{0.5N})=\frac{S_1+S_2}{N}$

Which is exactly the average of the original set.

In the general case, as mentioned in ttnphns's comment, this would be true only if you weigh the average by the sizes of the partitions. The proof is similar to the one I gave.

Comment: @user1546029 I just hope I'm not doing your homework...

Comment: Haha no, but that would be a cool class.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true, here's a counter example. Consider the set $\{2, 2, 4\}$. Then 
$$
\text{avg}(\{2, 2, 4\}) = \frac{8}{3}
$$ 
but 
$$
\text{avg}(\{\text{avg}(\{2\}), \text{avg}(\{2, 4\})\}) = \text{avg}(\{2, 3\}) = \frac{5}{2} \neq \frac{8}{3}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's partition our N elements into two sets (s1, s2) with sizes N1, N2 and averages A1, A2 respectively.

To to deduce the average A of N elements from this information ( N1, N2, A1, A2 ), we can use this formula:

```
   Average = Sum / NumElements 
=> Sum = Average * NumElements
```

Also:

```
   Average of all numbers = Sum of numbers / Count of numbers
```

Now

```
Sum of all numbers = N1*A1 + N2*A2
Total Elements = N1 + N2
```

Therefore **correct answer is**:

```
A = ( N1*A1 + N2*A2 ) / ( N1 + N2 )
```

Only when sizes of both partitions is same:

```
N1 = N2
A = (N1*A1 + N2*A2 )/ (N1+N2) = (N1*A1 + N1*A2)/(N1+N2) = N1*(A1+A2)/(2*N1)
=> A = (A1 + A2)/2
```

Hence the first answer only holds when size of both partitions is same.